# Tumblr API - how to upload multiple images to a Photoset

Tags: image, upload, tumblr

I am able to upload one picture but I can't create a photoset with multiple images using API.

Documentation says:
Paramater: Array (URL-encoded binary contents)

One or more image files (submit multiple times to create a slide show)

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm struggling with this now. Not sure what they meant with array of URL-encoded binary data.

Comment: @Arvin I've started a discussion on tumblr group. They say it's fixed but I still can't make it work.. https://groups.google.com/group/tumblr-api/browse_thread/thread/d32e0e6f9028960b/6865aa7b5eb3241d?lnk=gst&q=multiple+photos#6865aa7b5eb3241d

Comment: They posted a python example at https://gist.github.com/1198576 -- but I still can't figure it out in Objective C (using ASIFormDataRequest+OAuth.h). I can upload single files, but not multiple. I don't think ASIHTTPRequest 'url encodes binary data' when uploading files in the form data -- how is this done?

Comment: @miloshes hi, how did you upload single file i couldn't even accomplished yet. any example would be great. many thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's kind of a painful process, but I figured it out after studying the [python code Tumblr posted](https://gist.github.com/1198576).  In short, it requires getting the hexadecimal for the photo and then doing some substitutions.

I've created a simple [iOS / iPad / iPhone project on GitHub that uploads multiple photos to photosets using the Tumblr API](https://github.com/vvanhee/TumblrUploadr), based heavily on the [ASIHTTPRequest+OAuth project](https://github.com/keybuk/asi-http-request-oauth).  It works so far in my limited testing -- feel free to make use of it and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @miloshes - did this answer your question?  If so, marking this as the answer and/or an upvote would be much appreciated.  If not, what programming language are you using to do this?

Comment: @VictorVanHee, excellent work, the official tumblr API doc really drives me nut for hours.

Comment: @VictorVanHee Wow I can't believe you got this working.  What a nightmare!  I'm trying to do this in javascript.
Is stringWithoutURLEncoding the function you run the hex data through? What are the substitutions?
So far I have space -> + and \x -> %

Comment: @ggwarpig I can't believe it either. It's been so long I can scarcely remember what I did. Most of what you want is in https://github.com/vvanhee/TumblrUploadr/blob/master/NSData%2BURLEncode.m or user1569282's optimized answer.

Comment: @VictorVanHee I get issues with "Existing instance variable 'delegate' for property 'delegate' with assign attribute must be __unsafe unretained

Comment: @VictorVanHee Ignore my previous comment. You sir are an absolute LEGEND!!!!!! I have been trying for ages to get Tumblr photo posting working in my iOS app.... A man. I will certainly up vote your answer :)

Comment: @VictorVanHee Your library is supporting old ios version its better to update it for new upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

The new PhotoUpLink for iPhone uploads true Tumblr photosets. It is a free download from the App Store at http://uplink.to/5o example photosets at http://photouplink.tumblr.com

The Tumblr uploader is based on @VictorVanHee's epic. I did optimize the code by switching to straight C for the NSData stringWithoutURLEncoding subroutine:

```
- (NSString *) stringWithoutURLEncoding
{
    NSString *hexDataDesc = [self description];
    hexDataDesc = [[hexDataDesc stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    int hlen = [hexDataDesc length];

    NSString *hexDataDescU = [hexDataDesc uppercaseString];

    const char *hexcString = [hexDataDescU cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    char *newStringC = malloc(hlen *3);
    memset(newStringC, 0, hlen *3); 

    int xC= 0, upd = 3000, value = 0;

    char *componentC = malloc(5);   // = "XX";

    componentC[2] = 0;

    const char *px = "%x"; char ptc = '%';

    for (int x=0; x<hlen; x+=2)
    {                           
        componentC[0] = hexcString[x];
        componentC[1] = hexcString[x+1];

        value = 0;
        sscanf(componentC, px, &value);
        if ((value <=46 && value >= 45) || (value <=57 && value >= 48) || (value <=90 && value >= 65) || (value == 95) || (value <=122 && value >= 97)) //48-57, 65-90, 97-122
        {  
            newStringC[xC++] = (char)value;
        }
        else
        {
            newStringC[xC++] = ptc;
            newStringC[xC++] = (char)componentC[0];
            newStringC[xC++] = (char)componentC[1];
        }
    }

    NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithCString:newStringC encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *aNewString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@"+"];

    free (newStringC);
    free (componentC);

    return aNewString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with this too. Here is a gist in python of what ended up working for me:
https://gist.github.com/charlesbrandt/11eadaec114288d621fa

The trick is that all photos must be added to your post parameters with 'data[#]' for keys. ('data[0]', 'data[1]', etc)

Answer (score 0):

It's super simple, use 'source' parameter if you have only one image to upload, if there are multiple images, switch the parameter to 'data' and initialize it with **the array of image URLs**. For php tumblr client, following snippet can be used:

```
$paramsToPost = [
    'type' => 'photo',
    'tags' => 'tag1, tag2, tag2',
    'caption' => 'caption for photo(s)',
    'link' => 'http://example.com/click-through-url'
];
if (is_array($imageData)) {
    $paramsToPost['data'] = $imageData;
} else {
    $paramsToPost['source'] = $imageData;
}
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
$client->setToken($token, $tokenSecret);
$response = $client->createPost($blogName, $paramsToPost);
```