# API to post on Tumblr

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, tumblr

I've been trying to upload an image to Tumblr from my iOS application for a little while now, but I can't get my method to work properly.

My current method uses ASIHTTPRequest and OAuthConsumer according to [this guide](http://hytgbn.net/2012/02/tip-of-uploading-images-to-tumblr-using-oauth-on-ios/).
However, I end up getting a 401 error (Authentication needed).
You can find the explanation for my problem [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tumblr-api/ksfOzYctCXM).

But my question is : Is there any other mean/API to post on Tumblr for iOS?
I saw that OAuthConsumer was not fully functional on that side, and I didn't find anything with the GTM.

Thanks.

Comment: For anyone out there Tumblrs OAuth and API for posting images is horrifying. Expect lots of pain and many hours getting it to work.

Comment: That's what I unfortunately went trough :) So if anyone is experiencing this, maybe I could help !

Comment: Just curious, how many hours did you waste? I think it was about 15 for me.

Comment: Just FYI That TumblrUploadr library uses GOBS of memory, in my app I went from 38 MB to 101 MB with a 4 MP image on my iPhone 4S. I am refactoring it now to be a little smarter about allocating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution to my problem a few time ago.
I first thought that it was a bit old and that it wouldn't work but in the end, implementing the [TumblrUploadr](https://github.com/vvanhee/TumblrUploadr) did the thing.

To sum it all, I achieved login with GTM-OAuth and uploading with TumblrUploadr. For those who seek a solution to the Tumblr API.

**Update** : Some info concerning GTMOAuth, if you want to use the callback, you have to add a flag in the GTMOAuthAuthentication.m > +(NSArray*)tokenAuthorizeKeys : add kOAuthCallbackKey in the array so that it will be taken into account. Else, you have no callback.

Comment: @Snaker..in that code you are not taking any user login credentials(Tumblr Email and Tumblr Password)from the user....then how can you post the photos..Please tell me ...actually i'm stuck with the Tumblr integration in iPhone...Thanks...

Comment: @AshokKumarIOS The OAuth System is made to avoid the user to transmit his informations to the application. Thus, GTMOAuth will generate a UIWebView in which the user will give his credentials to login, once done, you get a connection token that you can use to say : Hey, it's the token I got from this user's login. That's the first part from GTMOAuth.
After that, TumblrUploadr should do the work for you, I kinda remember it's pretty easy to use. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878662/tumblr-api-how-to-upload-multiple-images-to-a-photoset/7431731#7431731)