# Upload Image on tumblr in iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, sdk, sharing

I am really stuck with this issue for many days. In my app i need to upload image on tumblr, i have tried various tutorials and updates however none of them is working for posting images on tumblr.Please help me any one if you have done this.

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:photo];
//stop on error
if (!imageData) return NO;

//Create dictionary of post arguments
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"password",@"type",@"caption",nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    tumblrEmail,
                    tumblrPassword,
                    @"photo", caption, nil];
NSDictionary *keysDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

//create tumblr photo post
NSURLRequest *tumblrPost = [self createTumblrRequest:keysDict withData:imageData];
[keysDict release];

//send request, return YES if successful
NSURLConnection *tumblrConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:tumblrPost delegate:self];
if (!tumblrConnection) 
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to submit request");
    return NO;
} 
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Request submitted");
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    [tumblrConnection release];
    return YES;
}

-(NSURLRequest *)createTumblrRequest:(NSDictionary *)postKeys withData:(NSData *)data
{
 //create the URL POST Request to tumblr
 NSURL *tumblrURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/kashifjilani.tumblr.com/posts"];
 NSMutableURLRequest *tumblrPost = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:tumblrURL];
 [tumblrPost setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Add the header info
NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];
[tumblrPost addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

//create the body
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//add key values from the NSDictionary object
NSEnumerator *keys = [postKeys keyEnumerator];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < [postKeys count]; i++) {
    NSString *tempKey = [keys nextObject];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",tempKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[postKeys objectForKey:tempKey]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

//add data field and file data
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//add the body to the post
[tumblrPost setHTTPBody:postBody];

return tumblrPost;
}
```

Comment: Show us some of your code or what errors are you getting?

Comment: I am trying to post the code on it,however not working

Comment: You mean you can't post code on stackoverflow? Make sure your code is concise and show us where you are getting the error.

Comment: I have edited my question and posted the code, In console it is showing request submitted however not any images uploaded on tumblr

Comment: Did you check my update code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourUploadImage, 0.9);
NSMutableURLRequest *aRequest = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[aRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.tumblr.com/api/write"]];
[aRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";
//NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[aRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

/*
 now lets create the body of the post
 */
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:Tumblr_UserName_Here dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:Tumblr_Password_Here dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary]
                  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"photo" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"; filename=\"upload.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: image/jpg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:imageData];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

if(comment available here)
{
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] 
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"caption\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[commentString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[aRequest setHTTPBody:body];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:aRequest delegate:self];
```

Now `delegate` of `NSURLConnection`

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  if(connection)
    NSLog(@"Success");
  else
    NSLog(@"Something Wrong");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
{
   NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
}
```

Comment: Hey Prince thanks for the valuable information, i have tried the above steps which you have provided however still not working, it is showing me success in NSLog however not working or post anything to tumblr

Comment: use authenticated user in tumblr as Tumblr_UserName_ and Tumblr_Password should be correct then and then you will be able to post

Comment: I am using correct username and password for tumblr, one mor thing, what do you mean by if(comment available here), what type of value we can give in that

Comment: if u want to add comment in image like if(CommentAvailable){ post comment}

Comment: UIImage *imagePassed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture1.jpg"];   NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imagePassed); and using kashifjilani as a username in tumblr username account, image is in resource folder

Comment: [body appendData:[@"kashifjilani" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; this is what i am using.

Comment: have your forgot to add password also

Comment: haaa, i have added password however its not working, do we need to add any kind of library like oAuth or any other one.

Comment: @Kashif are succeeded in that plz let me know ...because i'm struggling with the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for a long time too, but I figured out how to post easily.
You can see my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142608/api-to-post-on-tumblr) for an answer to this. If you have any problem with it, I'd be glad to help.