# Binary Image POST - iOS

Tags: ios, image, post, tumblr, url-encoding

I have an app which makes a OAuth 1.0a POST request to the Tumblr API. I have been following their documentation for how to upload a photo and although I have set the parameters, it doesn't work.

The Tumblr API Documentation states that you need these in your parameters:

source - (string) - The photo source URL

data - (Array URL-encoded binary contents) - One or more image files (submit multiple times to create a slide show)

So I have setup my POST request as follows but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is my code:

```
// Tumblr POST Request.
NSString *inputted_text = [inputted_text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_selected);

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:TUMBL_POST, tumblr_profilename];

NSDictionary *parameters;

if (media_post_check == 0) {
            // Text post.

            parameters = @{@"api_key" : TUMBL_CONSUMER_KEY,
                           @"type" : @"text",
                           @"body" : inputted_text};
        }

        else if (media_post_check == 1) {
            // Photo post.

            NSData *data_64 = [imageData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0];

            parameters = @{@"api_key" : TUMBL_CONSUMER_KEY,
                           @"type" : @"photo",
                           @"caption" : inputted_text,
                           @"data" : @[data_64]};
        }

        else if (media_post_check == 2) {
            // Video post.

            parameters = @{@"api_key" : TUMBL_CONSUMER_KEY,
                           @"type" : @"link",
                           @"title" : @"Hello there",
                           @"url" : pub_video_url};
        }

        // Build authorized request based on path, parameters, tokens, timestamp etc.
        NSURLRequest *preparedRequest = [OAuth1Controller preparedRequestForPath:path parameters:parameters HTTPmethod:@"POST" oauthToken:token_tumblr oauthSecret:token_secret_tumblr];

        NSData *urlData;
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *error;

        // Make synchronous request.
        urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:preparedRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSLog(@"%@", response);
```

Do I need to send the image data or a link to it? What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

I am now getting this error response:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0x112a50a90 {NSUnderlyingError=0x10d6e1370 "The network connection was lost.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/supertecnoboff.tumblr.com/post?api_key=wPqSZcRrJM4Rxu9oRECjcAzcvkq8EPwYq2LN98W13U39tDRPbZ&caption=Test%2520star&data%5B%5D=%3C6956424f%20527730206a........data...........14d6a%2048686871%204876672f%202f394763%2045684a68%205a574d41%2041414141%205355564f%20524b3543%205949493d%3E&type=photo, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}
```

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't manage to solve the problem myself. But after a lot of searching I came across this StackOverflow post of a developer who made a great Tumblr Uploader Class for iOS. So helpful and works perfectly. If you are interested, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431731/1598906

Comment: It should be said that the class you are referencing is so easy to use and thats great. But its only available in Objective-C, those wanting a Swift version will need to make their own work around or find another library which can do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to send a NSDATA object of your image as `source`, the API expects a source URL.

> source - (string) - The photo source URL

Base64 encode the NSDATA object and set the key to `data` instead of `source`.

Comment: Well sir, thank you very much for your answer. I tired this but now I get a connection time out error every time... Which seems odd. All my other POST requests are working to Tumblr, so why does this one time out? (I have updated my code with what you said).

Comment: By the way technically the POST request does work and I do get a response, but the response seems to be an error. I have updated the post with the error.

Comment: use `@"data" : [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:nil]` to return a NSString object.

Comment: No I am still getting the same issue. The thing is imageData is of type NSData and image_selected is of type UIImage. So how can base64EncodedStringWithOptions work, because that requires a string does it not?

Comment: It should work, I'm not sure about the timeout error. You might want to take a look at this: https://app.box.com/s/x3zxni4bq08gznx2k4lb. Goodluck!

Comment: Hey I have been trying all day and looking at that project too. Still doesn't work. Do you by any chance have any other ideas?

Comment: Daniel thank you for your help. In the end I found another developer who made a Tumblr Uploader Class. But I appreciate your time anyway sir :) I have up voted your answer and have left the link to the other devs Tumblr Upload Class in my answer if you are interested.